How can const work at the end of the code?
How come the const styles can be declared and initialized after being used in the code (in the App function) since in javascript they cannot be accessed before their declaration, resulting in a ReferenceError ?
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


It's  due to hoisting. See the duplicate and also MDN

"since in javascript hoisting doesn't exist for let or const" That statement is wrong. Hoisting exists for variables declared with let or const. Do you have a reference for your statement?

its not a duplicate! this particular situation is not specified

How is it not specified? The variable declaration is hoisted. It's in the function closure. Your case is not a special case. It's the common case.

"In summary, while both let and const are hoisted, the TDZ enforces a stricter rule, preventing their use before declaration, which contributes to more reliable and predictable code."
Nevertheless, the styles constant doesn't break the code being at the end of the code, as it should in other situations

The declaration is hoisted. The function is called after the variable is initialized. The code looks correct to me. If you call App() before const styles =..., you get an error. "How come the const styles can be declared and initialized after being used in the code" It's not declared or initialized after being used. It's being used after the initialization.

Maybe you should run the code in your debugger or add some debug logs to see the order of evaluation. It seems like that's the actual problem here. There is a misunderstanding of the evaluation order.

"since in javascript they cannot be accessed before their declaration" styles is not accessed before its declaration. It's accessed after its initialization. If you don't understand that, set a breakpoint at return (, another breakpoint at const styles = StyleSheet.create({, run the app with your debugger and see the order. First, the breakpoint at const styles = StyleSheet.create({ is triggered and then, the breakpoint at return ( is triggered.
